# How to Get the table in Bigquery from gcs bucket from a pipe delimited csv File?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

while expecting the records to be fitted in each column, all the records are fitting into single column. What are the additional parameters to be add in to fit the pipe delimited csv into Biq query table form gcs bucket?

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

# TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the table to create.
# table_id = "your-project.your_dataset.your_table_name"

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=[
    bigquery.SchemaField("name", "STRING"),
    bigquery.SchemaField("post_abbr", "STRING"),
],
skip_leading_rows=1, field_delimiter="|",
source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
)
uri = "gs://cloud-samples-data/bigquery/us-states/us-states.csv"

load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
uri, table_id, job_config=job_config
)  # Make an API request.
load_job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.
destination_table = client.get_table(table_id)  # Make an API request.
print("Loaded {} rows.".format(destination_table.num_rows)
```

Error:

```
 400 Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column position 20, but line starting at position:667 contains only 20 columns.
```

Comment: How many columns do you have? Are you sure that all your lines are good (right number of column on each line)?

Comment: I have 20 columns. Yes all the lines are good, but the fieldelimiter Iam using a pipe.
what if we have empty rows? would it cause any issue?

Comment: What's the difference with the line 667?

Comment: What do you mean by empty rows. Do you mean empty columns?the number of delimiter that is pipe “|” should be 19. Could you just ensure that it’s there fir all rows considering you have 20 columns